# Azure B2C - JWT Signature validation failed

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-msal

I have setup MSAL to fetch tokens from Azure AD B2C, setup dotnet core WebAPI to accept JWT tokens. Pointed WebApi at the Authority Endpoint:

```cs
 services.AddAuthentication(options =>
        {
            options.DefaultScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        }).AddJwtBearer(jwtOptions =>
        {
            string tenant = Configuration["AzureAdB2C:Tenant"], policy = Configuration["AzureAdB2C:Policy"], clientId = Configuration["AzureAdB2C:ClientId"];
            jwtOptions.Authority = $"https://login.microsoftonline.com/tfp/{tenant}/{policy}/v2.0/";
            jwtOptions.Audience = clientId;
            jwtOptions.Events = new JwtBearerEvents
            {
                OnAuthenticationFailed = AuthenticationFailed
            };
        });
```

as per the samples. MSAL is configured to use the same policy and same client Id and receives token.

MSAL Authority - `https://login.microsoftonline.com/tfp/{tenant}.onmicrosoft.com/{policy}/v2.0`.

However, that AuthFailed event handler just returns
`IDX10501: Signature validation failed. Unable to match keys.`
and bounces the auth as a 401.

I went looking for signing keys and the `kid` of the token is not the same as the kid listed at the discovery endpoint.

`https://login.microsoftonline.com/tfp/{tenant}/{policy}/discovery/v2.0/keys`

Any ideas?

Comment: You must not be getting tokens from that location then.  Who was the `iss` of the token?

Comment: `https://login.microsoftonline.com/{guid}/v2.0`, This wasn't the same as the one configured in the portal. Will test later!

Comment: @spottedmahn, hole-in-one! Configured the portal to return the `iss` claim in the shorter format and everything works.

Comment: Nice!  You should post an answer... how did you configure it in the portal?  Love the golf reference btw 

Comment: Can you add your `authority` value of msal.js?  [Reference](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-javascript-msal-singlepageapp/blob/master/index.html#L40)

Answer (score 3):

[image: Azure Policy SSO Options]

Seems that I had not selected the correct Issuer claim setting. MSAL was grabbing its token using the `https://login.microsoftonline.com/{guid}/v2.0` endpoint whereas WebAPI was using the `https://login.microsoftonline.com/tfp/{guid}/{policy}/v2.0/` issuer.

As per the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-token-session-sso#token-compatibility-settings) this isn't an openid compatible endpoint, but works fine for B2C. Pays to check over the two different claim sets!

Comment: FYI, you can use the [Gaussian Blur in pain.net](https://www.getpaint.net/doc/latest/EffectsBlursMenu.html#6) to redact information (instead of trying to black stuff out).